# Is it possible to make the login_window() function only run when the login button is clicked/activated?

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible to make the login_window() function only run when the login button is clicked/activated?  I have the following code and it shows login window when program starts.  I would like it only to show when I click the  button.  I'm new to python.  Thank you.

```
from tkinter import *

def login_window():
    login = Tk()
    email = Entry(login).grid(row=0, column=1)
    email_text = Label(login, text='Email or Username').grid(row=0, column=0)
login_window()

def root_window():
    root = Tk()
    ...
    loginbutton = Button(root, height=2, width=30, text='Login', command=login_window)
    loginbutton.grid(row=0, column=0)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `login_window()` function, below where it is defined, as it is run once the program starts.